# Prove $(\lnot p \to p) \to p$ in 19 steps

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

While revisiting "Mathematical Logic", I noticed a quiz that I had never worked out. It requires to prove

$$\{\} \vdash (\lnot p \to p) \to p$$

in 19 steps.

To be clear, each "step" should be in one of the following forms:

1. $p \to (q \to p)$ (L1)
2. $(p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to q) \to (p \to r))$ (L2)
3. $(p \to q) \to (\lnot q \to \lnot p)$ (L3)
4. $q$, provided that both $p$ and $p \to q$ have appeared in previous steps (Modus Ponens, MP)

(According to the book, using MP twice in an expression counts as 2 steps, and similar counting method holds for other expressions)

I still can't work this out, any one point out a way?

---

For example, here's a valid proof of $\{p \to q, q \to r\} \vdash p \to r$ in 7 steps:

> 1. $(q \to r) \to (p \to (q \to r))$ (L1)
> 2. $q \to r$ (Assumption)
> 3. $p \to (q \to r)$ (1, 2, MP)
> 4. $(p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to q) \to (p \to r))$ (L2)
> 5. $(p \to q) \to (p \to r)$ (3, 4, MP)
> 6. $p \to q$ (Assumption)
> 7. $p \to r$ (5, 6, MP)

Comment: Are you sure about 3) ? Maybe is the reversed implication...

Comment: @Mauro Not sure, but it's safe to assume $\lnot \lnot p = p$

Comment: Please name and shame your source here. What you are trying to prove is not valid in intuitionistic propositional logic, but your "steps' are intuitionistically acceptable. $\lnot\lnot p = p$ cannot be proved using these "steps".

Answer (score 1):

*Sketch of the proof*.

I'll use the following axiom in place of (L3) :

> (L3') $\vdash (¬p→¬q) → (q→p)$.

The [axiom system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms) (L1), (L2) and (L3') is complete for classical propositional logic.

With it we can prove (L3) as well as *Double Negation* laws and

> (A) $\vdash A \to A$.

---

1) $\vdash \lnot A \to (\lnot B \to \lnot A)$ --- (L1)

2) $\vdash (¬B→¬A) → (A→B)$ --- (L3')

> (B) $\vdash \lnot A \to (A→B)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *Trans* (you have proved it)

1) $\vdash (\lnot A \to (A \to \lnot B)) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to \lnot B))$ --- (L2)

2) $\vdash \lnot A \to (A \to \lnot B)$ --- from (B) with $\lnot B$ in place of $B$

3) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to \lnot B)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *MP*

> (C) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to (B \to A)$ --- from 3) and (L3') by *Trans*

---

1) $\vdash (\lnot p \to p) \to ((\lnot p \to p) \to p)$ --- from (C) with $(\lnot p \to p)$ in place of $B$

2) suitable version of (L2)

3) $\vdash ((\lnot p \to p) \to (\lnot p \to p)) \to ((\lnot p \to p) \to p)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *MP*

4) $\vdash (\lnot p \to p) \to (\lnot p \to p)$ --- from (A)

> 5) $\vdash (\lnot p \to p) \to p$ --- from 3) and 4) by *MP*

Answer (score 1):

First, Mauro is right to question your third axiom, for your L1,L2,L3, okus Modus Ponens is not complete ... and in fact with those you *cannot* prove $(\neg p \to p) \to p$

To see why, take the following non-standard semantics for the variables and their operators:

All statements still take a value of $T$ or $F$, and the $\to$ is defined as normal, but $\neg p$ will always return $F$

Then L1 and L2 are of course still tautologies, since they do not involve any $\neg$, but L3 is a tautology as well. And, using Modus Ponens, you can only infer further tautologies from tautologies.

However, $(\neg p \to p) \to p$ is no longer a tautology. With $p=F$, you get $(\neg F \to F) \to F = (F \to F) \to F = T \to F = F$

Therefore, $(\neg p \to p) \to p$ cannot be derived using your axioms and inference rule as stated.

(note that a similar argument can be used to show that $\neg \neg p \to p$ can also not be proven: this time, define $\neg$ such that it always evaluates to $T$. Then L1,L2,L3 are still tautologies, and MP can only derie tautologies from tautologies, but $\neg \neg p \to p$ is not a tautology, since with $P=F$, you get $\neg \neg p \to p = \neg \neg F \to F = \neg T \to F = T \to F = F$)

Following Mauro's suggestion to replace your third axiom with $(\neg p \to \neg q) \to (q \to p)$ (which is the 'standard' third axiom of the Lukasciewicz system .. which *is* complete), and working out his proof schema, you get:

\begin{array}{lll}
1&\neg p \to (\neg \neg (\neg p \to p) \to \neg p) & L1\\
2&(\neg \neg (\neg p \to p) \to \neg p) \to (p \to \neg (\neg p \to p))&L3'\\
3&((\neg \neg (\neg p \to p) \to \neg p) \to (p \to \neg (\neg p \to p)))\to (\neg p \to ((\neg \neg (\neg p \to p) \to \neg p) \to (p \to \neg (\neg p \to p))))&L1\\
4&\neg p \to ((\neg \neg (\neg p \to p) \to \neg p) \to (p \to \neg (\neg p \to p)))&MP \ 3,2\\
5&(\neg p \to ((\neg \neg (\neg p \to p) \to \neg p) \to (p \to \neg (\neg p \to p))))\to( (\neg p \to (\neg \neg (\neg p \to p) \to \neg p))\to (\neg p \to (p \to \neg (\neg p \to p))))&L2\\
6& (\neg p \to (\neg \neg (\neg p \to p) \to \neg p))\to (\neg p \to (p \to \neg (\neg p \to p)))&MP \ 5,4\\
7&\neg p \to (p \to \neg (\neg p \to p))&MP \ 6,1\\
8&(\neg p \to (p \to \neg (\neg p \to p)))\to ((\neg p \to p) \to (\neg p \to \neg (\neg p \to p)))&L2\\
9&(\neg p \to p) \to (\neg p \to \neg (\neg p \to p))&MP \ 8,7\\
10&(\neg p \to \neg (\neg p \to p)) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to p)& L3\\
11&((\neg p \to \neg (\neg p \to p)) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to p)) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to ((\neg p \to \neg (\neg p \to p)) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to p)))&L1\\
12&(\neg p \to p) \to ((\neg p \to \neg (\neg p \to p)) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to p))&MP \ 11, 10\\
13&((\neg p \to p) \to ((\neg p \to \neg (\neg p \to p)) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to p)))\to (((\neg p \to p) \to (\neg p \to \neg (\neg p \to p))) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to p)))&L2\\
14&((\neg p \to p) \to (\neg p \to \neg (\neg p \to p))) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to p))&MP \ 13, 12\\
15&(\neg p \to p) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to p)&MP \ 14, 9\\
16&(\neg p \to p) \to ((p \to (\neg p \to p)) \to (\neg p \to p))&L1\\
17&((\neg p \to p) \to ((p \to (\neg p \to p)) \to (\neg p \to p)))\to (((\neg p \to p) \to (p \to (\neg p \to p))) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to (\neg p \to p)))&L2\\
18&((\neg p \to p) \to (p \to (\neg p \to p))) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to (\neg p \to p))&MP \ 17, 16\\
19& (\neg p \to p) \to (p \to (\neg p \to p))& L1\\
20&(\neg p \to p) \to (\neg p \to p)&MP \ 18, 19\\
21&((\neg p \to p) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to p)) \to (((\neg p \to p) \to (\neg p \to p)) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to p))&L2\\
22&((\neg p \to p) \to (\neg p \to p)) \to ((\neg p \to p) \to p)&MP \ 21,15\\
23&(\neg p \to p) \to p&MP \ 22,20\\
\end{array}

So .... that's 23 lines, rather than 19 ... pretty good ... but not quite short enough... or maybe we are still using the wrong axiom for axiom 3?